# Best way to test production app on smaller set of users

Tags: android, google-play

The client is not very confident in its QA team and asked to perform installs of new versions of their Android app by providing the updates to only smaller set (subset) of their whole user base on Google Play. Is the A/B testing on Google Play the right way to go or there is a better alternative?

Thanks

Comment: You can either invite specified users to alpha beta test your app in Google Play or you can use "testing tracks" https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/test-tracks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the staged rollout feature on Google Play, using which you set a certain percentage of users to get the update (E.g. 10%). Then as more users update and you gain confidence that the update works properly, you can increase the rollout percentage.

By using this method the users will not have to do anything to opt in, they would be instead randomly chosen.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it on Google Play Console by publishing Alpha Beta versions that some users will join then tracking them.

Or handle it by your own; defining feature toggles that will be enabled for some users from the backend.